# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() - when comparing string with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of data frames but in a few cases, the list can also contain a string.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"df_column":["df_value"]})
a = ['skip',df]

if "skip" in a:
    print("yes")
```

The above gives output as `yes` because the list contains a string.

But in case if the list doesn't contain a string for eg

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"df_column":["df_value"]})
    a = [df,df]
    
    if "skip" in a:
        print("yes")
```

Now the above code gives an error  `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
How can I handle this?

Comment: NB. It will also fail if the string is after a dataframe. The first code only works because python stops testing the rest of the list after the first match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to avoid checking `pandas` all together see e.g. `[df , 'skip']` would fail - it's just a matter of order.

For starters you can only filter strings in `a`:

```py
if "skip" in filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), a):
    print("yes")
```

Comment: This answer is clean and efficient (no need for costly computations)

Answer (score 2):

Filter out `DataFrame`s, so comparing working nice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"df_column":["df_value"]})
a = [df,df,'skip']

#filter out DataFrames
#a = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame)]
#or filter strings
a = [x for x in a if isinstance(x, str)]
print (a)
['skip']

if "skip" in a:
    print("yes")
```

---

One idea is convert DataFrames to strings by [`DataFrame.to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) in list comprehension, but it is slowier:

```
a = [x.to_string() if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) else x for x in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the handling of the pandas DataFrame magic methods.

So you could make them numpy arrays:

```
>>> 'skip' in [df.to_numpy(), df.to_numpy()]
False
>>> 'skip' in [df.to_numpy(), df.to_numpy(), 'skip']
True
>>>
```

---

The reason is that the `in` functions checks equality for each element in the list, but obviously `'skip' == df` would throw an error.

So the way to fix would be the above, or the below:

```
if "skip" in map(str, a):
    print("yes")
```

`in`s implementation might be roughly:

```
for element in sequence:
    if element == target:
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I was trying to push **df** directly into MongoDB as below-

```
db.collection.insertMany(df)
```

but I need to send as below

```
db.collection.insertMany(df.to_dict('records'))
```